# Yii UrlManager Action OR Controller

Tags: php, regex, url, yii, yii-url-manager

Is it possible in Yii UrlManager rules to set rule  OR site/? For example there's "action Contacts in SiteController" and "controller MediController". Yii must use action from SiteController if it exists or user MediaController/index if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UrlManager, It will search from Top to Down.

So upto my knowledge, you can not define two CONTROLLER/ACTION for same Url alias.

But you can use controller forward in siteController. If your condition not satisfy then forward to mediaController.

```
$this->forward('media/index');
```

Hope helps !!

Comment: Its what I was writing :( +1

Comment: Yep, i just did it before saw your answer. Thx :)

Comment: Still you should accept it as an answer so that it could guide others too :)